# Spring batch job status configuration

Tags: spring-batch

I want to be able to set the step and job status to failed when the writer throws exceptions. After doing some debugging and examining the spring batch source-code I noticed that the `RepeatTemplate` is configured with a `SimpleRetryExceptionHandler` that considers the `BatchRuntimeException` as a fatal exception and hence sets the job status to FAILED, so I wrapped the code in my writer in a try-catch that wraps the `RuntimeException` in a `BatchRuntimeException` and now the job and step statuses are set to FAILED, as I wanted. I am unsure if this is the proper way to do it though, as I couldn't find it documented anywhere and the documentation for the `BatchRuntimeException` doesn't say anything about it either. So, the question would be: is this the proper way to do it?

Another thing I thought of was if it makes sense to FAIL a job if the write fails, but I think this makes sense given the use-case I have, which is something like this: read entries from database using a stream reader (which configures the query to run against the database), then use a stream writer to send those entries via email or http (retrieve configuration where to send the items in the stream open method). If everything is successful then update the database entries with a status SENT, if an error occurs during the doOpen/open/write methods then invoke a `StepExecutionListener` to send a notification email that the job failed. This is one of the reasons why I need to have the job status to FAILED, so that the `StepExecutionListener` (which checks the `ExitCode` to be FAILED) gets executed properly. The second reason is that I want to use the spring Batch Admin app to manage the jobs and if the job appears as COMPLETED, although the writing failed, this seems misleading since the whole point of the job is to send the items.This way, the job can be restarted if it failed, after the configuration is changed (e.g. the to email address is properly configured).

Also, if the write calls fail, then then entry in the database should have their status updated to FAILED, which I am planning to do in the onWriteError of an `ItemWriteListener` inside a new transaction, since the current one is going to be rolled back.

I posted all this long description just to be sure that I am not working against the intent of the framework here, with trying to set the job status to FAILED from the writer.

Looking forward for your thoughts on this.

Greetings,
Cristi

P.S.: The job is configured like that:

```
<batch:job id="job">
    <batch:step id="step">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" reader-transactional-queue="true" commit-interval="#{properties['export.page.size']}"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="failedStepListener"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

LATER EDIT: The reader and writer configurations are below:

```
<bean name="reader" class="...LeadsReader" scope="step">
    <property name="campaignId" value="#{jobParameters[campaignId]}" />
    <property name="partnerId" value="#{jobParameters[partnerId]}" />
    <property name="from" value="#{jobParameters[from]}" />
    <property name="to" value="#{jobParameters[to]}" />
    <property name="saveState" value="false" /> <!-- we use a database flag to indicate processed records -->
</bean>

<bean name="writer" class="...LeadsItemWriter"  scope="step">
    <property name="campaignId" value="#{jobParameters[campaignId]}" />
</bean>
```

The code for the writer is:

```
public class LeadsItemWriter extends AbstractItemStreamItemWriter<Object[]> {

//fields and setters omitted

public LeadsItemWriter() {
    setName(ClassUtils.getShortName(LeadsItemWriter.class));
}

@Override
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    super.open(executionContext);
    PartnerCommunicationDTO partnerCommunicationDTO = this.leadableService.getByCampaignId(this.campaignId)
            .getPartnerCommDTO();
    this.transportConfig = partnerCommunicationDTO != null ? partnerCommunicationDTO.getTransportConfig() : null;
    this.encoding = partnerCommunicationDTO != null ? partnerCommunicationDTO.getEnconding() : null;
    if (this.transportConfig == null) {
        throw new ItemStreamException ("Failed to retrieve the transport configuration for campaign id: "
                + this.campaignId);
    }
    PageRequestDTO pageRequestDTO = this.pageRequestMapper.map(partnerCommunicationDTO);
    if (pageRequestDTO == null) {
        throw new ItemStreamException("Wrong transport mapping configured for campaign id: " + this.campaignId);
    }
    this.columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (LeadColumnDTO leadColumnDTO : pageRequestDTO.getColumns()) {
        this.columnNames.add(leadColumnDTO.getName());
    }
}

@Override
public void write(List<? extends Object[]> items) throws Exception {
    try {
        if (this.transportConfig.getTransportType() == TransportConfigEnum.EMAIL) {
            this.leadExporterService.sendLeads(items, this.columnNames, this.transportConfig, this.encoding);
        } else {
            for (Object[] lead : items) {
                this.leadExporterService.sendLead(lead, this.columnNames, this.transportConfig, this.encoding);
            }
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Encountered exception while sending leads.", e);
        //wrap exception so that the job fails and the notification listener gets called
        throw new BatchRuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}

The code for the reader:

```
public class LeadsReader extends AbstractPagingItemReader<Object[]> {

//fields and setters omitted

public LeadsReader() {
    setName(ClassUtils.getShortName(LeadsReader.class));
}

@Override
protected void doOpen() throws Exception {
    this.pageRequestDTO = this.pageRequestMapper.map(this.leadableService.getByCampaignId(this.campaignId)
            .getPartnerCommDTO());
    if (pageRequestDTO == null) {
        throw new ItemStreamException("Wrong transport mapping configured for campaign id: " + this.campaignId);
    }
    this.timeInterval = new LeadTimeIntervalDTO(this.from != null ? of(this.from,
            LeadQueryFilterParam.Comparison.GT) : null,
            this.to != null ? of(this.to, LeadQueryFilterParam.Comparison.LE) : null);

    super.doOpen();
}

private LeadFilterDTO of(Date date, LeadQueryFilterParam.Comparison comparison) {
    LeadFilterDTO filterDTO = new LeadFilterDTO();
    filterDTO.setColumn(CREATION_DATE);
    filterDTO.setSqlType(DATE);
    filterDTO.setComparison(comparison.name());
    filterDTO.setValue(DateUtil.format(date, Validator.DATE_FORMAT));
    return filterDTO;
}

@Override
protected void doReadPage() {
    if (results == null) {
        results = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    } else {
        results.clear();
    }
    if (this.pageRequestDTO != null) {
        results.addAll(LeadsReader.this.leadStorageService.listLeads(
                LeadsReader.this.pageRequestDTO.getColumns(),
                LeadsReader.this.getFilters(),
                LeadsReader.this.pageRequestDTO.getQueryOrderByParams(),
                LeadsReader.this.pageRequestDTO.isUniqueByEmail(), LeadsReader.this.timeInterval,
                (long) getPage() + 1, (long) getPageSize()).getExportedLeadsRows());
    }

}

private List<LeadFilterDTO> getFilters() {

    List<LeadFilterDTO> filtersList = new ArrayList<>();

    LeadFilterDTO campaignFilter = new LeadFilterDTO();
    campaignFilter.setColumn(CAMPAIGN_ID);
    campaignFilter.setValue(Long.toString(campaignId));
    campaignFilter.setSqlType(BIGINTEGER);
    filtersList.add(campaignFilter);

    LeadFilterDTO partnerFilter = new LeadFilterDTO();
    partnerFilter.setColumn(PARTNER_ID);
    partnerFilter.setValue(Long.toString(partnerId));
    partnerFilter.setSqlType(BIGINTEGER);
    filtersList.add(partnerFilter);

    LeadFilterDTO statusFilter = new LeadFilterDTO();
    statusFilter.setColumn(STATUS);
    statusFilter.setValue("VALID");
    statusFilter.setSqlType(CHAR);

    filtersList.add(statusFilter);

    return filtersList;
}

@Override
protected void doJumpToPage(int itemIndex) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is thrown by a component within the framework (specifically an `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, `ItemWriter`, or `Tasklet`) and isn't caught, the step executing the component will be marked as failed without you doing anything additional.  If a step fails, the job is marked as failed as well (this is what allows it to be re-started).

In short, you shouldn't need to do anything extra to get the job to fail when an exception is being thrown.

Comment: This is not exactly true for all cases: e.g, if the reader is configured with reader-transactional-queue="true" then the StepParserStepFactoryBean calls the the createFaultTolerantStep method which in turn configures the RepeatTemplate with a SimpleRetryExceptionHandler (in createRetryOperations()) which swallows the exception.

Comment: Sure, I've added the configuration for them in the description.

Comment: Since you're using a custom reader and writer, can you include the code for them as well?

Comment: I've added them to the description.

Comment: Hi Guys, I ended up in a similar issue. Basically I am partitioning my step and my writer throws an BatchRuntimeException for all the partitions. But my job status is COMPLETED. I believe it should be FAILED. Also  in my BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table partition0 is FAILED and partition1 is FAILED but the final step is showing as ABANDONED